# Input Dialog with mask using RegExp

Tags: regex, delphi, dialog

How it's possible create in Delphi Xe a input dialog with regex mask. for example restrict only 3 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi doesn't have a text input that accepts a regular expression (regex) for an input mask. You can do something similar though, fairly easily.

Create your own form, with either a `TMaskEdit` with an `EditMask` of `000;1;_` or a `TSpinEdit` set to a `MinValue` of `100` and a `MaxValue` of `999`. Add two buttons (`Ok` and `Cancel`), with `ModalResult` set to `mrOK` and `mrCancel` respectively.

Add a property that reads the value of whichever control you use (`StrToInt(MaskEdit1.Text);` or `SpinEdit1.Value`), such as

```
property Value: Integer read GetValue;
```

where the `GetValue` is simply:

```
procedure TNumberInputForm.GetValue: Integer;
begin
  Result := SpinEdit1.Value;  // or Result := StrToInt(MaskEdit1.Text);
end;
```

Then use the code:

```
Value := 0;
NumberInputForm := TNumberInputForm.Create;
try
  if NumberInputForm.ShowModal = mrOK then
    Value := FrmNumberInput.Value;
finally
  NumberInputForm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: thx nice and easy way to do it , Just one question, how i can block the access of TMaskEdit1 from the others unit. I try put the component as private but in this case exception is generated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In order for the form to be created, controls it contains must be published (so that RTTI is generated to be used in streaming). Why would it matter if the MaskEdit is visible from another unit? Perhaps you should create a separate question and ask that there, where there is room to explain what it is you want to do.

Comment: for example, from my mainform I can do this: NumberInputForm.MaskEdit1:="123", How I can block directly acces from the components from others units. I want that the MaskEdit1 value just can be modified or readed using my own declared methods

Comment: The only way to prevent that is to create your MaskEdit at runtime instead of at designtime, setting all of the properties in your code. You can then declare it as `private` instead of `published`, because it doesn't need to be streamed in when the form is created. Since its then no longer a `published` or `public` field of `NumberInputForm`, that code would no longer compile.